# How to continuously update the value of a tensor in a loop

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, random, random-seed

So I am trying to continuously update a tensor in my code in a loop by assigning it with a new value in each iteration. genRandMat function assigns the variable **a1** with a random **MxN matrix** comprising 0 and 1 with **frequency of 1 being decided with probability pt**.

Here is the code I ran -

```py
np.random.seed(0)
tf.set_random_seed(0)
def genRandMat(M,N,pt):
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(M,N), p=[1-pt, pt]), dtype=tf.float32)

a1=tf.Variable(genRandMat(1,10,0.5))
a2=a1.assign(genRandMat(1,10,0.5))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(5):
        print(a1.eval())
        sess.run(a2)
        print(a1.eval())
        print("*************")
```

The result I expected was a new random tensor after every second print statement (due to update statement a2), ie 2nd, 4th, 6th... matrices should be updated, new random matrices.

Here is what I got instead

```sh
[[0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]]
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]]
*************
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]]
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]]
*************
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]]
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]]
*************
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]]
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]]
*************
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]]
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]]
*************
```

As you can see, the value of a1 changes once at the start with the 2nd print statement and then not anymore. I tried commenting out both random seeds but the result doesn't change. I want a new matrix after every update statement. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have generated the random value ones, and you keep assigning the same value again. To assign different value each time you need to generate random values using TensorFlow API, not numpy.

Alternatively, you could assign a new value without creating graph operations by using `tf.Variable.load()`:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
np.random.seed(0)
tf.set_random_seed(0)

def rand_mat(M=1, N=10, pt=0.5):
    return np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(M,N), p=[1-pt, pt])

a1 = tf.Variable(rand_mat(1, 10, 0.5))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in range(5):
        print(a1.eval())
        a1.load(rand_mat())
        print(a1.eval())
        print()
# [[1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0]]
# [[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]]
# 
# [[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]]
# [[1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0]]
# 
# [[1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0]]
# [[0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]]
# 
# [[0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]]
# [[0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]]
# 
# [[0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]]
# [[1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
```

With TensorFlow API you could do it like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

randint = tf.round(tf.random.uniform(shape=(1, 10)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(5):
        print(randint.eval())
        print()
# [[1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
# 
# [[1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]
# 
# [[1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
# 
# [[0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1.]]
# 
# [[1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks a lot. A slight caveat: I need a1 to be a tensor since I want to multiply it with other tensors later in my code. Can you suggest a similar menthod to generate random arrays using the TF API?